# React - show message only once depending on boolean

Tags: reactjs

I need to show a message only once depending on a boolean in redux state. When the boolean is false, the message should not show. The logic is:

- Initially the boolean is false
- If boolean is false, a popup should show automatically. The popup dispatches an action setting the boolean to true (it is saved to localState).
- The popup has a message which is set if boolean is false

The result is:

- The popup shows, and dispatches the action to set boolean to true.
- The message doesn't show at all because the boolean was updated to true.

Popup code:

```
 componentDidMount() {
         //if boolean is false, set it to true
         if(!this.props.popupHasShown) {
              this.props.popupHasShown() 
      }


 //set message if popup have not shown
    var initialMessage = !this.props.popupHasShown ? 'Hello! this is the message' : null;

render(){
    return(
       <div>
           <p>Popup!</p>
           {initialMessage && <p>{initialMessage}</p>}
      </div>
     )
}
```

You can open the popup manually , but that message should not display in that regular case.

So I don't know how to make that text visible the first time

Comment: can you close the pop up manually? because closing the pop-up should trigger the action to set the state on true, instead of the componentDidMount. You need to set a condition for dispatching the action that sets it on true (for example: onclick function or a timeout). Because component did mount will setit directly on true even without the possibility to read it.

Comment: That's a good idea.. yes it has an onClose which is triggered  either when clicking a close button, or clicking outside popup. I will try this.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. You could make an answer if you like.